# Is there a way to preview images from website without saving it on disk?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'd like to just display an image into a tkinter button from the web without actually downloading it. The link I'm using contains the raw image from the web in a png format. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. View image in what sense?

Comment: What did you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the image from the URL and load it in Tkinter:

```
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import requests

url = 'https://path.to/image.png'
response = requests.get(url)
load = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = Label(self, image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0, y=0)
```